# XAML build not able to run Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, xaml, tfs

I am trying to run Nunit Test using Visual Studio test Runner from XAML build in TFS,but i am getting error saying

**TF900547: The directory containing the assemblies for the Visual Studio Test Runner is not valid ''.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078089/tf900547-the-directory-containing-the-assemblies-for-the-visual-studio-test-run - this has been asked and answered before.

Comment: Do you use VSTS? If not, what's the version of your TFS? What's the version of VS on your build agent server?

Comment: I am using TFS 2015 Update 3.Visual studio is not installed in build server.How can it done without installing VS in the build server?If it is agents we need to install than please can you give me the link to download that

Comment: The steps are the same. I have Visual Studio installed in the build server, but may don't need, just refer to my steps and check result.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your history, I assume you are using VSTS, you can refer to these steps to run Nunit test:

1. Create a unit test project via VS
2. Install [NUnit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/) and [NUnit3TestAdapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/) packages
3. Add solution to source control (**if the package files not added to the source control, you can refer to the steps below**)
4. Open Source Control Explorer in VS
5. Add a new folder (e.g. Tools) and add Nuget.exe to the source control
6. Add bat file to your test project (For example: `Tools\nuget35.exe restore NUTest2\NUTest2.sln`)
7. Open XAML build definition and map Tools source folder to agent

[image]

8. Select Process section
9. Choose **TfvcTemplate.12.xaml** build template
10. In the **Advance** section of Build, specify **Pre-build script path** with previous bat file.

[image]

Comment: i want to run it through visual studio test runner

Comment: @Priya.D The steps are the same and the tests run by visual studio test runner.

Comment: @Priya.D What's the result now? Do you solve this issue?