# TFS 2012: F900547: The directory containing the assemblies for the Visual Studio Test Runner is not valid

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, visual-studio-2015

We have a *TFS 2012* Server and *Visual Studio 2015* on the Client side.
The Problem is that when I am building a project containing tests i get the following error on the TFS: `F900547: The directory containing the assemblies for the Visual Studio Test Runner is not valid`.

---

On [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163889/the-directory-containing-the-assemblies-for-the-visual-studio-test-runner-is-not) i got the information that i have to choose `MSTest` as the *test runner* in the *build definitions*.

But when i try this i get no options to choose for the *test runner*.

It is greyed out like described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078089/tf900547-the-directory-containing-the-assemblies-for-the-visual-studio-test-run?lq=1). The solution mentioned here is that I had to install a version of *Visual Studio 2013* on my build server to get it working.

I already have an installation of *Visual Studio 2015 Professional* installed on the server but it is still showing the error and i still have no more options to choose from as *test runner* than `Visual Studio Test runner`

---

Why do i not have `MSTest` as an option as the *test runner* and how can i fix this?

AND/OR

How can i fix the problem of having this error without installing *Visual Studio 2013* on the Build Server?

Comment: I have the same problem.